# Amazon Signature Encoding

Tags: encoding, urlencode, amazon-product-api

The Amazon documentation for "creating a signature" has some pretty specific requirements.  In particular, it asks me to:

> URL encode the parameter name and values according to the following rules:
>
> - Do not URL encode any of the unreserved characters that RFC 3986 defines. These unreserved characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, hyphen ( - ), underscore ( _ ), period ( . ), and tilde ( ~ ).
> - Percent encode all other characters with %XY, where X and Y are hex characters 0-9 and uppercase A-F.
> - Percent encode extended UTF-8 characters in the form %XY%ZA....
> - Percent encode the space character as %20 (and not +, as common encoding schemes do).

Does this encoding have a name?

Comment: Do you mean a name other than "Amazon signature encoding"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know if the encoding has a name, but it is defined by RFC 3689.  Once I knew that, finding a library was easy.

Comment: Actually it's RFC 3986